# questions about api of Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter

1.The api: stream.filter(). I read the documentation which said that all parameters can be optional. However, when I left it empty, it won't work.

2. Still the question with api. It is said that if I write code like below:

```
twitter_stream.filter(locations = [-180,-90, 180, 90])
```

It can filter all tweets with geological information. However, when I check the json data, I still find many tweets, the value of their attribute geo are still null.

3.I tried to use stream to get as many tweets as possible. However, it is said that it can get tweets in real time. will there be any parameters to set the time
like to collect tweets from 2013 to 2015

4.I tried to collect data through users and their followers and continue the same step until I get as many tweets as I want. So my code is like below:

```
import tweepy
import chardet
import json
import sys
#set one global list to store all user_names
users_unused = ["Raithan8"]
users_used = []
def process_or_store(tweet):
    print(json.dumps(tweet))

consumer_key = 
consumer_secret = 
access_token = 
access_token_secret = 

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

def getAllTweets():
    #initialize one empty list tw store all tweets
    screen_name = users_unused[0]
    users_unused.remove(screen_name)
    users_used.append(screen_name)
    print("this is the current user: " + screen_name)
    for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name = screen_name).items():
        if friend not in users_unused and friend not in users_used:
            users_unused.append(friend.screen_name)
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name = screen_name).items():
        if follower not in users_unused and follower not in users_used:
            users_unused.append(follower.screen_name)

    print(users_unused)
    print(users_used)
    alltweets = []
    #tweepy limits at most 200 tweets each time
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 200)
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    if not alltweets:
        return alltweets
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    while(len(new_tweets) <= 0):
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name, count = 200, max_id = oldest)
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    return alltweets

def storeTweets(alltweets, file_name = "tweets.json"):
    for tweet in alltweets:
        json_data = tweet._json
        data = json.dumps(tweet._json)
        with open(file_name, "a") as f:
            if json_data['geo'] is not None:
                f.write(data)
                f.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while(1):
        if not users_unused:
            break
        storeTweets(getAllTweets())
```

I don't why it runs so slow. Maybe it is mainly because I initialize tweepy API as below

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

But if I don't initialize it in this way, it will raise error below：

```
raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.RateLimitError: [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**2)** There's a difference between a tweet with coordinates and filtering by location.

Filtering by location means that the sender is located in the range of your filter. If you set it globally `twitter_stream.filter(locations = [-180,-90, 180, 90])` it will return tweets for people who set their country name in their preferences.

If you need to filter by coordinates (a tweet that has a coordinates) you can take a look at [my blog post](https://piratefache.ch/real-time-tweets-with-tweepy-and-cartopy/). But basically you need to set a listener and then check if the tweet have some coordinates.

**3 and 4)** Twitter's Search API and Twitter's Streaming API are different in many ways and restrictions about [rate limits (Tweepy)](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rate_limits.html) and [Twitter rate limit](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting).

You have a **limitation** about how many tweets you want to get (in the past).

Check again Tweepy API because `wait_on_rate_limit` set as true just wait that your current limit window is available again. That's why it's "slow" as you said.

However using streaming API doesn't have such restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your help